# Error updating table cell using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I've got a table displaying a list of order items. Each `row` contains 3 buttons, to decrement order quantity by one, increase order quantity by one and delete the entire item from the order. I am having a strange issue whereby when I decrement the order quantity of a particular row it causes the value stored in the second row to be updated...

This is where I set up the table:

```
if($.cookie('order_cookie') != undefined){
    productArray = JSON.parse($.cookie('order_cookie'));
    $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
}

//Reference to the order table
var ordertable = document.getElementById("ordertable");

    //Loop through the Array and display in the table
    for(var i = 0; i < productArray.length; i ++){
       // console.log(productArray[i]);
        console.log("Order Item " + i);
        console.log("StockCode: " + productArray[i].stockCode);
        console.log("Quantity: " + productArray[i].quantity);

        var row = ordertable.insertRow(i + 1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = productArray[i].stockCode;
        cell2.innerHTML = productArray[i].quantity;
        cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='-' class='removeBtn'/><input type='button' value='+' class='addBtn'/><input type='button' value='Delete' class='deleteBtn'/>"
    }
```

This is where I decrement the order quantity for the item in the table

```
//Change the total 
$('.removeBtn').click(function(){ //Remove 1 from quantity

    console.log(productArray);
    console.log("remove");
    var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    console.log(row);
    console.log(row.rowIndex);
    var elementToUpdate = row.rowIndex - 1;
    productArray[elementToUpdate].quantity--;
    cell2.innerHTML = productArray[elementToUpdate].quantity;
   // $.cookie('order_cookie', JSON.stringify(productArray), { expires: 1, path: '/' });
});
```

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening? I think it might be something to do with the fact that I am generating the table using `Javascript` as opposed to `HTML` but I am not entirely sure.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: If you can, please set up a Jsfiddle demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Can you show your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event Delegation`. you add `.removeBtn` class dynamically

```
$("#ordertable").on("click" , ".removeBtn" , function(){ 

      // your code come here
});
```

Comment: It would be better to bind the event to the table instead of binding it directly to every button.

Comment: _` bind the event to the table instead of binding it directly to every button`_...what???

Comment: @Jai
You can bind a click listener to the table instead of every button.
This way you won't need any delegate.

Comment: @Garzun - Ok tell me how to bind the event to the table ?

Comment: @Garzun then you must also mention that sudharsan should put this code then  in the `doc ready` otherwise this won't work if put it outside, while delegating to `$(document)` does not need doc ready block. as doc is already there before dom ready.

Comment: @Jai
You should always wait till the dom is ready if you are trying to manipulate it.

Comment: @Garzun that's right but what about asynchronous calls and this issue which sudarshan solved. creating new dom entries and binding events to it.

Comment: @Jai
surdarshan already modified his answer, so he is doing what I mentioned.

btw: I was not the downvoter